# PHP: session.auto_start

Tags: php, session

I have two projects  in the same server, their settings conflict in the "session.auto_start", related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378324/php-setting-variables-in-if-construct/1378342#1378342). Can I have the session.auto_start "ON" despite the other project contains codes such as session_start()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using apache, and have the right Options, you can enable session.auto_start with a .htaccess file containing this line: php_flag session.auto_start 1

Or you might be able to put it in your global apache config in that  tag.

Answer (score 5):

Do you need to independent sessions per user? I imagine you could just have one script check if a session already exists, like:

```
if(!($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If a session is already started. Then you will get an E_NOTICE error. [`session_start()` docs.](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have conflict not because of "session.auto_start" you just need to set individual [session_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) for each project.